# Is it possible to engage with WIFI / WIFI DIRECT via html5/js?

Tags: javascript, html, api, wifi

I would like to make a website that uses wifi information.
Can I do this with any HTML5 API's?
I would like the current wifi host name and peer connections, others connected to the same wifi host.

EDIT: 
For those curious about potential HTML5 WIFI API's, it is not currently possible. This is relevant, but experimental https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/connection

Comment: What kind of wifi information are you talking about? A concrete example can make *worlds* of difference in clarity. For instance, do you mean (say) signal strength? Wifi network name? Also, is your "html app" browser-based? Or some kind of embedded thing?

Comment: Will your app run in a browser?

Comment: yes it will run in a browser

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, accessing WIFI information is not possible via javascript in a browser.

Comment: +1, Your knowledge is up to date in this area :)